# A4J Polling throws error on reREnder

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a JSF(2.2.5) project using RichFaces(4.3.6) and PrimeFaces (5.0) with the following code

```
<h:panelGroup>
        <a4j:region>
            <h:form>
                <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="15000" enabled="#{card.poll}" 
                    reRender="swimlanes @parent" actionListener="#{card.reloadData}" />
            </h:form>
        </a4j:region>
        <h:form>
            <a4j:outputPanel id="swimlanes">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    Stuff
                </h:panelGroup>
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Which is very similar to the example of the RichFaces page but when the poll becomes enabled I get the following error and no reRendering occurs

```
debug[09:41:56.298]: New request added to queue. Queue requestGroupingId changed to j_idt20:poll
    debug[09:41:56.299]: Queue will wait 0ms before submit
    debug[09:41:56.299]: richfaces.queue: will submit request NOW
    info [09:41:56.302]: Received 'begin' event from <span id=j_idt20:poll ...>
    info [09:41:57.310]: Received 'beforedomupdate' event from <span id=j_idt20:poll ...>
    debug[09:41:57.312]: Server returned responseText: <partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="j_idt20:poll"><![CDATA[<span style="display:none;" id="j_idt20:poll"><script type="text/javascript">new RichFaces.ui.Poll("j_idt20:poll",{"enabled":true,"interval":15000,"ontimer":function(event){RichFaces.ajax("j_idt20:poll",event,{"incId":"1"} )}} )</script></span>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[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]]></update><extension id="org.richfaces.extension"><render>j_idt20:poll</render></extension></changes></partial-response>
    warn [09:41:57.318]: richfaces.queue: ajax submit error: During update: javax.faces.ViewState not found
    debug[09:41:57.319]: richfaces.queue: Nothing to submit
    error[09:41:57.320]: Received 'error@malformedXML' event from <span id=j_idt20:poll ...>
    error[09:41:57.321]: [status=200] During update: javax.faces.ViewState not found
    info [09:41:57.321]: Received 'complete' event from <span id=j_idt20:poll ...>
```

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Agile Development Tools</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Any idea how to fix this please?

Comment: `reRender` attribute is not supported in RichFaces 4.x. You need to use `render` attribute in `a4j:poll`. [See doc](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/)

Comment: I changed it to render and the same error was returned, I later removed the render attribute (since it's not marked as required) and I still got the same problem

Comment: `render` values are not supposed to be comma separated?

Comment: I tried render="swimlanes", render=" ", and without the render attribute and the error still appeared

Comment: No... `render="swimlanes,@parent"`

Comment: @SamanthaCatania can you include the content of your `web.xml` in your question? Also, maybe you have an error in the content of `Stuff` ?!

Comment: I tried render="swimlanes,@parent" but the error persisted. Stuff consists of a loop that outputs some divs each containing a command link. These get displayed fine but the number of divs do not get updated if the value changes in the backend.

Comment: Even though the error is persisting the page seems to be updating (scrollbars reset position) but the contents isn't changing

Answer (score 0):

It's a BUG in RichFaces 4.3.7 and earlier versions!

This Bug doesn't exist in RF Version 4.5 and 5.0

Comment: This might be correct but could you provide the needed informations to confirm, as a link to said bug description in the official notes.